# Connect to MySQL database with Node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react-native

I'm experiencing an issue when trying to connect to a MySQL database with Node.JS in my React Native application.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    port: 8889,
    database: "blabla"
}); 

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

I can access to phpmyadmin without any problem (same user and password)
but when I execute the JS file the terminal seems to load but stay stuck like this:

[image]

I don't think that there is a link with React but I really have no idea about it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

According to the mysql docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql you need to add `con.end();` after you are finished with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I just understood that I didn't exit the script, but it's working (sorry).

The line to end the script for Node.js beginners like me:

```
process.exit()
```

Comment: Until the connection is closed (see Kodie Grantham's answer), Node will not exit the process itself. Once you close the connection, Node will exit too.